# Arithmetic mean and geometric mean inequality - proving $[(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)]^7 > 7^7a^4b^4c^4$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c > 0$, then prove that $[(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)]^7 > 7^7a^4b^4c^4$

I reached till : 
$8^7 > 7^7 \sqrt{abc}$

Can't move forward from there. Please help!

Comment: This [was asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802976/if-a-b-c-0-prove-that-1a1b1c7-77a4b4c4/1803464#1803464) a few days ago.

Comment: @ayush I think you have missed a power of 7

Comment: If you put large value of a, b,c ,you would see it